# Can infinity be a limiting point?

Tags: general-topology, analysis

My initial guess would be no, as infinity is not a point.

Using the same definition of a limiting point from [What is and how to find a limiting point?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2897184/what-is-and-how-to-find-a-limiting-point) , and say for the sequence of negative integers $s_n=${-1,-2,-3,-4...}.

$\lim_{n \to \infty }s_n = -\infty$ and since $-\infty$ is not a point in the negative integers I am guessing that means (negative)infinity is a limiting point of $s_n$. So what would be the correct interpretation here? Is infinity a (divergent)limit of the sequence or a limiting point?

Comment: In analysis we often use a construction called the [extended real numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line), which adds the points $+\infty$ and $-\infty$ to the ordinary real numbers.  In the usual topology the real numbers are homeomorphic to an open interval, and adding the two "endpoints" at infinity gives us a topological space that is homeomorphic to a closed interval.  In that sense the notion of a (real) limit at infinity can be treated in a consistent way as a "point" at infinity.  Your example is of course that of a limit at $-\infty$.

Comment: @hardmath so this means infinity is a limit point? Since I guess when working with these type of problems the extended real numbers thing is implied.

Comment: Yes, if you are working in the context of extended real numbers, then it makes perfect sense to treat the limit at infinity (resp. at negative infinity) as a limit point.  Of course we haven't usually introduced this construction at the level of first or second year calculus, but if you are taking a topology course, then this would be a good technique to have at your disposal.  In particular the extended real number line is a *compact* topological space.  If this answers your Question, you are welcome to write it up yourself (or invite me to do so).

Comment: @hardmath yea that answers my question perfectly. I am not sure what you mean by write it up myself, so I think you can just copy and paste what you said in the comments and that will be fine for me as an answer.

Comment: sorry to bother you again @hardmath , but I was wondering that since -$\infty$ is apart of the sequence $s_n$ on the extended real numbers doesn't that mean -$\infty$ becomes an isolated point and so can't be a limiting point and the sequence $s_n =${-1,-2,-3...-$\infty$} which kind of becomes a finite set and so no limiting points exist.

Comment: It often happens that the limit of a sequence is not equal to any value in the sequence, e.g. $\lim 1/n = 0$.

Comment: @M.Winter yea just found that out. didn't know a limiting point can be called that as well

Comment: @glockm15 I got the link from your answer. This is an automatically generated comment because I voted to close. Don't worry, this is just to clean up. You got your answer anyways. Just one note: since your answer is copied word-by-word from the comments, this would be an appropriate case to make it community wiki, in order to not take credit for someone elses work (despite he not wrote it down as an answer). It would be different when you would have used your own words.

Answer (score 1):

In analysis we often use a construction called the [extended real numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line), which adds the points +∞ and −∞ to the ordinary real numbers. In the usual topology the real numbers are homeomorphic to an open interval, and adding the two "endpoints" at infinity gives us a topological space that is homeomorphic to a closed interval. In that sense the notion of a (real) limit at infinity can be treated in a consistent way as a "point" at infinity. Your example is of course that of a limit at −∞.

if you are working in the context of extended real numbers, then it makes perfect sense to treat the limit at infinity (resp. at negative infinity) as a limit point. Of course we haven't usually introduced this construction at the level of first or second year calculus, but if you are taking a topology course, then this would be a good technique to have at your disposal. In particular the extended real number line is a compact topological space.

Answered in comments by hardmath

I guess this post is also a duplicate as limiting point can also be accumulation point

[How can infinity be an accumulation point?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/777031/how-can-infinity-be-an-accumulation-point)